# Kotlin: automatic getter not accessible in lambda

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin supposedly creates getters and setters automatically, but...

```
class Foo {
  var id = 1
}

class Bar {
  var foos = listOf(Foo())

  fun printFooIds() {
    foos.forEach { println(it.id) }       // works
    foos.forEach { println(it.getId()) }  // error "Unresolved reference: getId"
  }
}
```

Why the error? How can we access the auto-generated getter here?

Comment: By calling `foo.id` of course

Answer (score 4):

When you write down `foo.id` (or `it.id`) in Kotlin, you *are* accessing the property through its getter, whether it's the default one that returns the backing field or a custom one you wrote for it.

```
val id = foo.id   // this calls the getter
foo.id = 1        // this calls the setter
```

What you're seeing isn't an error, you're supposed to be using `foo.id` to read the property when you're writing Kotlin code.

---

Reading a property both with the property access syntax `foo.id` and `foo.getId()` is only an option when you're accessing Java properties from Kotlin. The second call is the original Java syntax of course, and the first is a [Kotlin-to-Java interop feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters) to make the syntax more Kotlin-friendly.

Similarly, for Java-to-Kotlin interop, you will see the property as a getter-setter pair from Java, and use it like this:

```
foo.getId()
foo.setId(1)
```